# Hibernate TransientObjectException when referencing transient entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PE_HOME")
@Cacheable
public class Home extends DefEntity implements IHome {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = true, unique = false)
    private String description = null;

    @Column(name = "INDICE", nullable = true, unique = false)
    private Integer indice = null;

    public Home() {
        super();
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getIndice() {
        return this.indice;
    }

    public void setIndice(Integer indice) {
        this.indice = indice;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "PE_PERSON")
public class Person extends DefEntity implements IPerson {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Home.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_HOME", nullable = true, unique = false)
    private IHome home = null;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    public IHome getHome() {
        return this.home;
    }

    public void setHome(IHome home) {
        this.home = home;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PE_FAMILY")
@Cacheable
public class Family extends DefEntity implements IFamily {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Person.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderColumn(name = "LIST_INDEX", nullable = false)
    @JoinTable(name = "PE_FAMILY_PERSONS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_FAMILY") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PERSON") }, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ID_PERSON", "LIST_INDEX" }))
    private List<IPerson> persons = new ArrayList<IPerson>();

    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = FamilyDetails.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_FAM_DET", nullable = true, unique = true)
    private IFamilyDetails familyDetails = null;

    public Family() {
        super();
    }

    public List<IPerson> getPersons() {
        return this.persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<IPerson> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public IFamilyDetails getFamilyDetails() {
        return this.familyDetails;
    }

    public void setFamilyDetails(IFamilyDetails familyDetails) {
        this.familyDetails = familyDetails;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "PE_FAMILY_DETAILS")
@Cacheable
public class FamilyDetails extends DefEntity implements IFamilyDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Home.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "AX_FAM_DET_HOMES", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_FAM_DET") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_HOME") })
    private Set<IHome> homes = new HashSet<IHome>();

    public FamilyDetails() {
        super();
    }

    public Set<IHome> getHomes() {
        return this.homes;
    }

    public void setHomes(Set<IHome> homes) {
        this.homes = homes;
    }
}

public class FamilyManager {

    public void saveFamily(final IFamily family) {
        updateFamilyDetails(family);
        familyDao.save(family);
    }

    private void updateFamilyDetails(final IFamily family) {
        IFamilyDetails details = family.getFamilyDetails();
        if (details == null) {
            details = new FamilyDetails();
            family.setFamilyDetails(details);
        }
        details.getHomes().clear();
        for (IPerson p : family.getPersons()) {
            if (p.getHome() != null) {
                details.getHomes().add(p.getHome());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the Home entity is persisted along with Person entity that is persisted along with Family entity. Also the FamilyDetails entity is persisted along with Family entity. I was trying to update homes attribute from FamilyDetails before persisting the Family entity. The problem is that the homes added are not yet persisted when I added them in the collection. I believed that when they would be persisted along with Persons entities from Family they would be updated also in homes collection from FamilyDetails but I get an

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.model.impl.Home;

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Try adding cascade to Home entity in FamilyDetails
`@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Home.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE )`

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously: save the `Home`s before you save the `FamilyDetail`s, which can be achieved by adding a `@ManyToMany` annotation with a `cascade` attribute as grizzly noted in his comment.

Think about it: Not configuring any cascading behavior is like saying: I take care of persisting those. Why should JPA take care to persisting them AND persisting them in the right order, just because this is configured somewhere else relative to some other entity.